# Uncheck other radio buttons when checking one, having problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify

Im having problems with my UI when selecting radio buttons via click on a div:

**I have a loop that shows various radio buttons:**

```
{% for product in collections.regalos.products %}
<li class="grid__item large--one-third gift-card">
  <div class="gift-select-option-inside">
    <input required type="radio" class="gift-input" 
    name="properties[Regalo]" value="{{ product.title }}"> <label>{{ 
    product.title }}</label>
  </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**I want to apply a class when a radio is checked by toggling it, but it will repeat on every radio input (the other inputs wont disable their class when clicking on a new one)**

```
<script>
  $(".gift-card").on("click", function() {
      var giftradio = $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
      giftradio.parent('div').toggleClass('selectedgift');
      $('#builder-t-1').append("<span class='ok'>OK</span>");
  });

   if($('.gift-input').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
</script>
```

**Basically, I don't want this:**
Everything gets duplicated each time I click on a radio. I only need 1 div to be selected and one alert on the tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to uncheck all radio button, then select the right one.

```
<script>
  $(".gift-card").on("click", function() {
    // deselect all 
    $('.gift-input').prop('checked', false).parent('div').removeClass('selectedgift'); 

    var giftradio = $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
    giftradio.parent('div').toggleClass('selectedgift');

    $('#builder-t-1').html("<span class='ok'>OK</span>");
  });

  if($('.gift-input').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
</script>
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: Can you make sure that each time event is triggering by `console.log('Event is triggered');`?

Comment: Its triggering every time, but still, when clicking on a radio, the other radios should remove their classes and its not happening ...

Comment: Ok now with the edit its working! Nice! How about the append part? Is there something I can do so that only an alert "OK" is shown when any radio is selected?

Comment: I'm not clear, you mean `if($('.gift-input').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }` line is not working or else?

Comment: Nevermind just changed append for .HTML and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think writing a Jquery script to uncheck is an overkill, instead try the below;

```
{% for product in collections.regalos.products %}
<li class="grid__item large--one-third gift-card">
  <div class="gift-select-option-inside">
    <input required type="radio" class="gift-input" 
    name="gift-select-checkbox" value="{{ product.title }}"> <label>{{ 
    product.title }}</label>
  </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}

<script>
  $(".gift-card").on("click", function() {
      var giftRadioVal=$('.gift-card :checked').val();
      //Do anything with this val
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It keeps adding the class to every input without eliminating the others :/

Comment: That should not be a problem if you are trying to capture the value of the checked radio. have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/g1foycr2/5/